# How do I query this Mongodb Object?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I am trying to query this Mongodb object but can't seem to get to certain data points that I need. How do I get to say the imagePath data? The data is saved in a table called orders. I have tried dot notation i.e. order.cart[0] but can't figure out how to get deeper in the array.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5976b6b11306910658b1ff57"),
    "address": "6210 place",
    "name": "frank",
    "paymentId": "ch_1AjJRVDfJryYeuMpJC80cp5k",
    "email": "g@mail.com",
    "time": ISODate("2017-07-25T03:10:41.522Z"),
    "cart": [
        {
            "items": {
                "5975228a215c0f074b64f58e": {
                    "item": {
                        "_id": "5975228a215c0f074b64f58e",
                        "title": "Bracelet 3",
                        "imagePath": "https://www.costco.com/wcsstore/CostcoUSBCCatalogAssetStore/category-tiles/pearl-bracelets.jpg",
                        "description": "This is bracelet 3",
                        "price": 12,
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 12
                },
                "59752242215c0f074b64f58c": {
                    "item": {
                        "_id": "59752242215c0f074b64f58c",
                        "title": "Bracelet 1",
                        "imagePath": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/160/0/12655872/il_340x270.1187191078_i2ha.jpg",
                        "description": "This is bracelet 1",
                        "price": 10,
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "qty": 2,
                    "price": 20
                },
                "5975226a215c0f074b64f58d": {
                    "item": {
                        "_id": "5975226a215c0f074b64f58d",
                        "title": "Bracelet 2",
                        "imagePath": "http://media.tiffany.com/is/image/Tiffany/EcomBrowseM/paloma-picasso-knot-bead-bracelet-34946183_963148_ED.jpg?op_usm=1.00,1.00,6.00&defaultImage=NoImageAvailable&&",
                        "description": "This is bracelet 2",
                        "price": 5,
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 5
                }
            },
            "totalQty": 4,
            "totalPrice": 37
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far? And what are you trying to do?  I'm guessing loop through cart[0].items?

Comment: Actual "dot notation" is `"cart.0"` for issuing a "query" to MongoDB, which is different from JavaScript syntax. It really is not clear what "query" you want to do, since you actually don't say it. Your inner content of `"items"` is a problem. You have used "named keys" instead of making the "items" members of an array. In fact it looks like `"cart"` has been made a single element array in **error**, where in fact you intended the array to be the "items". Or at least that is what the structure "should" be instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = {
    "address": "6210 place",
    "name": "frank",
    "paymentId": "ch_1AjJRVDfJ ryYeuMpJC80cp5k",
    "email": "g@mail.com",
    "cart": [
        {
            "items": {
                "59752 28a215c0f074b64f58e": {
                    "item": {
                        "_id": "5975228a215c0f074b64f58e",
                        "title": "Bracelet 3",
                        "imagePath": "https:// www.costco.com/wcsstore/CostcoUSBCCatalogAssetStore/category-tiles/pearl-bracelets.jpg",
                        "description": "This is brace let 3",
                        "price": 12,
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 12
                },
                "59752242215c0f074b64f58c": {
                    "item": {
                        "_id": "597522 42215c0f074b64f58c",
                        "title": "Bracelet 1",
                        "imagePath": "https://img0.etsystatic.com/160/0/12655872/il_340x270.11871 91078_i2ha.jpg",
                        "description": "This is bracelet 1",
                        "price": 10,
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "qty": 2,
                    "price": 20
                },
                "5975226a2 15c0f074b64f58d": {
                    "item": {
                        "_id": "5975226a215c0f074b64f58d",
                        "title": "Bracelet 2",
                        "imagePath": "http://media .tiffany.com/is/image/Tiffany/EcomBrowseM/paloma-picasso-knot-bead-bracelet-34946183_963148_ED.jpg?op_usm=1.00,1.00,6.0 0&defaultImage=NoImageAvailable&&",
                        "description": "This is bracelet 2",
                        "price": 5,
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    "qty": 1,
                    "price": 5
                }
            },
            "totalQty": 4,
            "totalPrice": 37
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
};

console.log('looping through Object.keys')
Object.keys(data.cart[0].items).forEach(key => {
  const cartItem = data.cart[0].items[key];
  console.log('cartItem.item.imagePath', cartItem.item.imagePath)
})

console.log('looping through Object.values')
Object.values(data.cart[0].items).forEach(cartItem=> {
  
  console.log('cartItem.item.imagePath', cartItem.item.imagePath)
})
```

Since your cart item.items is an object.  You can leverage [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to loop through an object properties.

Comment: This worked! I was able to loop through correctly. Thank you for the quick reply and even more so with little information (sorry I am new to this), but thanks again!

Comment: @cisco See my updated answer... you can also leverage Object.values (probably easier)